# Using ANTLR for static analysis of Java source file

Tags: java, antlr

Does anyone have a complete implementation (possibly github or googlecode) for using an ANTLR grammar file and Java source code to analyze Java source.  For example, I want to simply be able to count the number of variables, method, etc.

Also using a recent version of ANTLR.

Comment: I'd assume you can download a Java parser/AST builder directly from the ANTLR website (therefore meeting "a recent version of ANTLR").  Writing a tree crawler to count methods and fields is pretty easy.  The "etc." part means nobody can guess what else you want; why won't a standard metrics tool do?

Comment: If you are considering doing static analysis for errors or security than you will probably need more than the AST and the tree rewrite rules provided by ANTLR. You might want you use ANTLR in combination with [Stratego/XT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratego/XT). I don’t know of anyone has a free public version of what you seek. Good question. If you want profesional quality tools check out Ira's profile.

Comment: Counting variables and methods would be much easier by looking at the compiled bytecode, for example using the ASM bytecode framework.

Comment: @JörnHorstmann: The counts you get from examining the bytecode may be different than the counts you get from examining the source. Inlined compile-time constants, bridge methods, etc. will result in different numbers. Things get more complicated whether variables/methods/etc. of nested types count toward the totals of the enclosing type.

Comment: Why not use http://www.kclee.de/clemens/java/javancss/ as starting point ? It does not use ANTLR but javacc. By the way it probably already generates all metrics you are looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I thought I'd take a crack at this over my lunch break. This may not completely solve your problem, but it might give you a place to start. The example assumes you're doing everything in the same directory.

1. Download the [ANTLR source](https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/tarball/master) from GitHub. The pre-compiled "complete" JAR from the ANTLR site contains a known bug. The GitHub repo has the fix.
2. Extract the ANTLR tarball.

   ```
   % tar xzf antlr-antlr3-release-3.4-150-g8312471.tar.gz
   ```
3. Build the ANTLR "complete" JAR.

   ```
   % cd antlr-antlr3-8312471
   % mvn -N install
   % mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true
   % mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true package assembly:assembly
   % cd -
   ```
4. Download a [Java grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1207932239307/Java1_5Grammars/Java.g). There are others, but I know this one works.
5. Compile the grammar to Java source.

   ```
   % mkdir com/habelitz/jsobjectizer/unmarshaller/antlrbridge/generated
   % mv *.g com/habelitz/jsobjectizer/unmarshaller/antlrbridge/generated
   % java -classpath antlr-antlr3-8312471/target/antlr-master-3.4.1-SNAPSHOT-completejar.jar org.antlr.Tool -o com/habelitz/jsobjectizer/unmarshaller/antlrbridge/generated Java.g
   ```
6. Compile the Java source.

   ```
   % javac -classpath antlr-antlr3-8312471/target/antlr-master-3.4.1-SNAPSHOT-completejar.jar com/habelitz/jsobjectizer/unmarshaller/antlrbridge/generated/*.java
   ```
7. Add the following source file, Main.java.

   ```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.List;

   import org.antlr.runtime.*;
   import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;

   import com.habelitz.jsobjectizer.unmarshaller.antlrbridge.generated.*;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String... args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, IOException, RecognitionException {
           JavaLexer lexer = new JavaLexer(new ANTLRFileStream(args[1], "UTF-8"));
           JavaParser parser = new JavaParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
           CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)(parser.javaSource().getTree());
           int type = ((Integer)(JavaParser.class.getDeclaredField(args[0]).get(null))).intValue();
           System.out.println(count(tree, type));
       }
       private static int count(CommonTree tree, int type) {
           int count = 0;
           List children = tree.getChildren();
           if (children != null) {
               for (Object child : children) {
                   count += count((CommonTree)(child), type);
               }
           }
           return ((tree.getType() != type) ? count : count + 1);
       }
   }
   ```
8. Compile.

   ```
   % javac -classpath .:antlr-antlr3-8312471/target/antlr-master-3.4.1-SNAPSHOT-completejar.jar Main.java
   ```
9. Select a type of Java source that you want to count; for example, `VAR_DECLARATOR`, `FUNCTION_METHOD_DECL`, or `VOID_METHOD_DECL`.

   ```
   % cat com/habelitz/jsobjectizer/unmarshaller/antlrbridge/generated/Java.tokens
   ```
10. Run on any file, including the recently created Main.java.

    ```
    % java -classpath .:antlr-antlr3-8312471/target/antlr-master-3.4.1-SNAPSHOT-completejar.jar Main VAR_DECLARATOR Main.java
    6
    ```

This is imperfect, of course. If you look closely, you may have noticed that the local variable of the enhanced `for` statement wasn't counted. For that, you'd need to use the type `FOR_EACH`, rather than `VAR_DECLARATOR`.

You'll need a good understanding of the elements of Java source, and be able to take reasonable guesses at how those match to the definitions of this particular grammar. You also won't be able to do counts of references. Declarations are easy, but counting uses of a field, for example, requires reference resolution. Does `p.C.f` refer to a static field `f` of a class `C` inside a package `p`, or does it refer to an instance field `f` of the object stored by a static field `C` of a class `p`? Basic parsers don't resolve references for languages as complex as Java, because the general case can be very difficult. If you want this level of control, you'll need to use a compiler (or something closer to it). The Eclipse compiler is a popular choice.

I should also mention that you have other options besides ANTLR. JavaCC is another parser generator. The static analysis tool PMD, which uses JavaCC as its parser generator, allows you to write custom rules that could be used for the kinds of counts you indicated.

Comment: From the point of view of simply counting instances of syntax (e.g., # variable declarations) this is a fine answer.  OP is opaque on what else he wants to do; static analysis usually goes far beyond just counting, and typically requires a symbol table and often requires flow analysis.  If he needs just counting, your solution is peaches (so +1); if he needs more, this won't cut it, name resolution let alone flow analysis for Java is difficult.

Comment: @IraBaxter: Agreed that my solution is possibly only partial. I have a suspicion that his needs are relatively uncomplicated, plus it was just fun going back to mess with ANTLR.

Comment: It is a vague question because I have never actually gotten a Java grammar to work with the recent version of antlr.  The syntax changed a great deal from the 2.0 release and 3.0.  A lot of the docs online were geared towards the older version.  It was throwing me off.  I was mostly interested in the syntax and approach with antlr.  My actual task was pretty basic.

Comment: Thanks, I finally revisited this.  I had many compile errors, trying to build antlr from source.  I eventually ended up only building the modules I need (antlr-complete, etc). I also had to turn off gpg as part of the build.  Other than that, the grammar worked as expected.